# Vectorizing with summation vs dot product

Tags: numpy

I am writing a simple linear regression cost function (Python) for a simple neural network. I have come across the following two alternate ways of summing the error (cost) over m examples using numpy (np) matrices.

The cost function is:

```
def compute_cost(X, Y, W):
m = Y.size;
H = h(X,W)
error = H-Y
J = (1/(2*m)) *  np.sum(error **2, axis=0) #1 (sum squared error over m examples)
return J
```

X is the input matrix.
Y is the output matrix (labels).
W is the weights matrix.

It seems that the statement:

```
J = (1/(2*m)) *  np.sum(error **2, axis=0) #1 (sum squared error over m examples)
```

can be replaced by:

```
J = (1/(2*m)) * np.dot(error.T, error) #2
```

with the same result.

I do not understand why np.dot is equivalent to summing over m examples or just why the two statements give the same result. Could you please provide some leads and also point me to some link(s) where I can read more and understand this relationship between np.sum and np.dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special, just simple linear algebra.

According to [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), `np.dot(a,b)` performs different operation on different types of inputs.

> If both a and b are 1-D arrays, it is inner product of vectors
>   (without complex conjugation).
>
> If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is
>   matrix multiplication, but using matmul or a @ b is preferred.

If your `error` is 1-D array, then the transpose `error.T` is equal to `error`, then the operation `np.dot` is the inner product of them, which equals to the sum of each element to the power of 2.

If your `error` is 2-D array, then you should follow matrix multiplication principle, so each row of `error.T` will multiply by each column of `error`. When your `error` is a column vector, then the result will be a 1*1 matrix, which is similar to a scalar. when your `error` is a 1-by-N row vector, then it returns an N-by-N matrix.